# How does one use mutually defined Streams in Idris?

Tags: idris

The issue I'm having may be more general than stated in the question. I'm trying to get the following program to work:

```
module Main
main: IO ()


process: Int -> Int
process req = req+1
server: Stream Int -> Stream Int
client: Int        -> Stream Int -> Stream Int
server (req :: reqs)           = process req :: server reqs
client initreq (resp :: resps) = initreq :: client resp resps
mutual
  reqsOut: Stream Int
  respsOut: Stream Int
  -- This fixes the segfault:
  -- reqsOut  = cycle [1, 2, 3, 4]
  reqsOut  = client 0 respsOut
  respsOut = server reqsOut

main = do
  printLn(take 5 reqsOut)
```

It will run if I swap out the definition of `reqsOut` with the commented version, but generates a segmentation fault as is. My guess is I'm using `mutual` incorrectly, but I'm not sure how.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that in function call the arguments gets evaluated beforehand, in particular case splits. Here in `client` the stream gets case splitted with `client initreq (req :: reqs)`, so `respsOut` in `client 0 respsOut` gets evaluated before the delayed tail:

```
reqsOut =
client 0 respsOut =
client 0 (case respsOut of (req :: reqs) => ...) =
client 0 (case (server regsOut) of (req :: regs) => ...) =
...
```

You can delay the split with

```
client initreq stream = initreq :: client (head stream) (tail stream)
```

But then you'd still have the infinite loop through `server`:

```
reqsOut =
client 0 respsOut =
client 0 (server regsOut) =
client 0 (case regsOut of (req :: reqs) => ...) =
...
```

You can delay the computation of `respsOut` by making the argument `Lazy`:

```
client : Int -> Lazy (Stream Int) -> Stream Int
client initreq stream = initreq :: client (head stream) (tail stream)
```

And now `client` can finally construct a `Stream Int` without evaluating its arguments:

```
client 0 respsOut =
0 :: Delay (client (head (Force respsOut)) (tail (Force respsOut))) : Stream int
```